# OpenEJBException in apache tomee 7.0.3

Tags: java, openjpa, apache-tomee, openejb, tomee-7

I am using apache tomee 7.0.3 as server container and using OpenJPA. While starting the server getting below excption. Please anybody can help me.

**Exception :**

```
WARNING: File error: <Deployments dir="apps/"> - Does not exist: C:\Work\EclipseWorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\apps
Sep 20, 2017 5:34:33 PM org.apache.openejb.util.OptionsLog info
INFO: Using 'openejb.deployments.classpath=false'
Sep 20, 2017 5:34:33 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating TransactionManager(id=Default Transaction Manager)
Sep 20, 2017 5:34:33 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating SecurityService(id=Tomcat Security Service)
Sep 20, 2017 5:34:33 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler createRecipe
INFO: Creating Resource(id=My DataSource)
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
Sep 20, 2017 5:34:38 PM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tds2-admin-service]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:854)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1607)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:763)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2227)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1038)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Sep 20, 2017 5:34:38 PM org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder startInternal
SEVERE: Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/tds2-admin-service]
org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: C:\Work\EclipseWorkSpace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp5\wtpwebapps\ca-acs-tds2-admin-service: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1042)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:718)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:873)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBRuntimeException: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.<init>(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.PersistenceBuilder.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceBuilder.java:157)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:867)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: <openjpa-2.4.2-r422266:1777108 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: There was an error when invoking the static newInstance method on the named factory class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory".  See the nested exception for details.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.newBrokerFactory(Bootstrap.java:73)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.getBrokerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:149)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProviderImpl.java:63)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable.call(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:109)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createDelegate(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:134)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: On a thread without an initialized context nor a classloader mapping a deployed app
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:287)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.getContext(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:263)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:298)
    at org.apache.openejb.cdi.ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.get(ThreadSingletonServiceImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansFinder.getSingletonInstance(WebBeansFinder.java:51)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.getInstance(WebBeansContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.webbeans.config.WebBeansContext.currentInstance(WebBeansContext.java:203)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$BmHandler.findBm(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:170)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.EntityManagerFactoryCallable$BmHandler.invoke(EntityManagerFactoryCallable.java:158)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.toString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.toString(AbstractMap.java:559)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1280)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:865)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:841)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.getMessage(Localizer.java:282)
    at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.toString(Localizer.java:309)
    at org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALog.record(JULOpenJPALog.java:130)
    at org.apache.openejb.openjpa.JULOpenJPALog.trace(JULOpenJPALog.java:72)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProductDerivation$ConfigurationProviderImpl.setInto(PersistenceProductDerivation.java:764)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newInstance(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.invokeFactory(Bootstrap.java:131)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.Bootstrap.newBrokerFactory(Bootstrap.java:66)
    ... 21 more
```

Comment: file persistence.xml will be helpfull

Comment: is there another stack trace in the log?

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher No..

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you start the server from Eclipse and deploy the application from Eclipse.

Take these steps to fix the problem:

1. From Eclipse Undeploy all projects from TomEE
2. Double click server to open its properties.
3. Select **Use Tomcat installation**

[image]